# Spinner listener not working

Tags: android

my app crashes with this code.. it doesnt even start up.. any ideas guys thanks
my app crashes with this code.. it doesnt even start up.. any ideas guys thanks

```
package com.about.bysk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class AboutActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(null, "a", 5);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

this makes my app crash. please help..

Comment: please provide the main.xml and log cat.... –

Comment: BTW  still show() is missing after the Toast .....

Comment: you can't pass null as context to Toast   Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, "a", 5).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `Listener` for your spinner and your class must implement `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
public class YourClass extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener { ... }
```

Then you must set `Listener` for your spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Or you can use it like anonymous class

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) { ... }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) { ... }
});
```

**Note:** If you want to show Toast, you must call `show()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you have not set the lisnter to spinner

as per you code do as below ...

1-public class AboutActivity extends Activity `implement OnItemSelectedListener`{

2- spinner.`setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`;

3- Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this,"RootBox",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).`show()`;

you can't pass null as context to Toast

```
Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to setlistner ... Also you din call show method with toast !!