# Android Multi Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to develop an android app with three spinners.
These three spinners will contain the information about the cars, which are brands, models, and engines.

1. So, after the first spinner(brand) is chosen, the contents of the second spinner(model) should be added depend on the selected brand.
2. Next, the second spinner will be selected and then the third spinner(engine) will be added.

I have searched with keyword "Android Multi Spinners" and "Android listener for spinners" on google and stackoverflow for almost a week, but I still didn't find the solution.

> Here are the links that I got the idea for my code
>
> - [multiple spinner's simple doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150834/multiple-spinners-simple-doubts)
> - [Spinner listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227951/spinner-listener-not-working)

So, I have two versions of my source code, but both of them didn't work. (Edited: Working now)

**For the first version**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AddCarActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spnBrand, spnModel, spnEngine;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_car);

        addItemsOnSpnBrand();   
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpnBrand() {
        spnBrand = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnBrand);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Get Brand Database and Add to List

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnBrand.setAdapter(dataAdapter);       

        addListenerOnSpnBrandItemSelection();
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpnBrandItemSelection() {
        spnBrand = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnBrand);       
        spnBrand.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                addItemOnSpnModel(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    public void addItemOnSpnModel(String inBrand) {
        spnModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnModel);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Get Model Database and Add to List

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnSeries.setAdapter(dataAdapter);      

        addListenerOnSpnModelItemSelection();
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpnModelItemSelection() {
        spnModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnModel);
        spnModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                addItemOnSpnEngine(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());               
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    public void addItemOnSpnEngine(String inModel) {
        spnEngine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnEngine);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        //Get Engine Database and Add to List

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnEngine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Here is my Second version**

```
public class AddCarActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner spnBrand, spnModel, spnEngine;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_car);

        addItemsOnSpnBrand();
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        int id = parent.getId();
        switch (id) 
        {
            case R.id.spnBrand:
                addItemOnSpnModel(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()); break;
            case R.id.spnModel:
                addItemOnSpnEngine(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()); break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        return;
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpnBrand() {
        spnBrand = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnBrand);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Get Brand Database and Add to List
    
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnBrand.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spnBrand.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void addItemOnSpnModel(String inBrand) {
        spnModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnModel);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Get Model Database and Add to List

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnModel.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spnModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void addItemOnSpnEngine(String inModel) {
        spnEngine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnEngine);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        //Get Engine Database and Add to List

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnEngine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone that have tried to help me. I just found the problem when retest the codes for answering Hip Hip Array. I use the wrong variable in addListenerOnSpnModelItemSelection(). I mistaken to use spnBrand instead of spnModel. Now, these two versions are worked, so I corrected them and hope that they will help the others that try to use the multi-spinners in android.

Comment: are you getting any errors when you run the app or is it just crashing out when you start it or whats happening?

Comment: Thanks Hip Hip Array, because of you I already found out the problem.
At first I use the wrong object to set the listener so it didn't work.

PS. Now, these two versions of codes is working fine with Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say,you have 3 spinners spinner_1,spinner_2 and spinner_3 then:

```
spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                            if(spinner_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Spin1-Item-1")){
                            {
                                  // set adapter to spinner_2 here for "Spin1-Item-1" selected
                            }
                            else if(spinner_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Spin1-Item-2"))
                            {
                                 // set adapter to spinner_2 for "Spin1-Item-2" not selected
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                 // set adapter to spinner_2 for "Spin1-Item-3" not selected
                            }
            }    
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
            }
});
spinner_2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                            if(spinner_2.getSelectedItem().equals("Spin2-Item-1")){
                            {
                                  // set adapter to spinner_3 here for "Spin2-Item-1" selected
                            }
                            else if(spinner_2.getSelectedItem().equals("Spin2-Item-2"))
                            {
                                 // set adapter to spinner_3 for "Spin2-Item-2" not selected
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                 // set adapter to spinner_3 for "Spin2-Item-3" not selected
                            }
            }    
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
            }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hiral for your help, I will try your codes and will also mark it as an answer if it works.

Comment: Your answer is similarly to my first version codes. The only one difference is I separated setOnItemSelectedListener() into the new function. and Yes, your code is worked.

Answer (score 1):

Bit long winded but give it a try

```
Public class HomePage extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener{

int orientation;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
Cursor c3, c2;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapterData;
int index = 0;
Spinner s[] = new Spinner[5];
TableRow row;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

//-----------Customized Adapter for Specialties----Database binded//
String[] columns2 =  {myDbHelper.KEY_ID, myDbHelper.KEY_TITLE};
String table2 = myDbHelper.DB_TABLE_NAME;
c2 = myDbHelper.getHandle().query(table2, columns2, "type = 'SuperTab'", null, myDbHelper.KEY_TITLE, null, myDbHelper.KEY_TITLE);
startManagingCursor(c2);
String[] from = new String[]{myDbHelper.KEY_TITLE};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
adapterData =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c2, from, to );
adapterData.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );


//-----------Customized Adapter for Location-----Database binded--//
    String[] columns3 =  {myDbHelper.KEY_ID, myDbHelper.KEY_LOCATION};
    String table3 = myDbHelper.DB_TABLE_NAME_LOCATION;
    c3 = myDbHelper.getHandle().query(table3, columns3, null, null, myDbHelper.KEY_LOCATION, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(c3);
    String[] from3 = new String[]{myDbHelper.KEY_LOCATION};
    int[] to3 = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapterData3 =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c3, from3, to3 );
        adapterData3.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
//--------------------------------------------------------------//

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.specialty_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapterData);      

Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.office_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapterData3);

Button search = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Search);
search.setOnClickListener(this);

Button searchNearMe = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Near_Me);
searchNearMe.setOnClickListener(this);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  

orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

s[index] =  new Spinner(this);
// s[index].setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
row = new TableRow(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
    long id) {
TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText2);   


Log.w("ID: ", "index=" + adapterData.getItemId(pos) + " " + c2.getCount() + " " + id + " callee " + view);

String sql = "sql" +                     id                                                                 ;

c2 = myDbHelper.getHandle().rawQuery(sql, null);
Log.w("ID Adapter: ", "index=" + adapterData.getItemId(pos) + " " + c2.getCount());

int thisOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

if (thisOrientation != orientation) {
    return;
}       

//--------sets hierarchy spinner to corresponding database-----//
String[] from = new String[]{myDbHelper.KEY_TITLE};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter adapterDataNew =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c2, from, to );
adapterDataNew.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
Log.w("Adapter Data New", "index=" + adapterDataNew.getItemId(pos) + " " + adapterDataNew.getCount());
//------------------------------------------------------------//

//-----------------Table Row for Landscape mode---------------//

TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)this.findViewById (R.id.Table);
TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
tlp.weight = 1;
tlp.setMargins(20, 15, 20, 0);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));       

//------------------------------------------------------------//

//------------------find Relative Layout by ID----------------//
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.rlay);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.spinner);
p.setMargins(15, 5, 15, 5);
//------------------------------------------------------------//

if (orientation != getResources().getConfiguration().ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    if (c2.getCount() > 0) {                
        relative.removeView(s[index]);
        relative.addView(s[index], android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        s[index].setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        s[index].setPromptId(R.string.Sub);
        s[index].setAdapter(adapterDataNew);
        s[index].setLayoutParams(p);
        tv.setPadding(10, 50, 10, 0);

        Log.w("Index value ", " " + index);

    }
    else {
        s[index].setVisibility(view.GONE);
        relative.removeView(s[index]);
        tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
else {
        if (c2.getCount() > 0) {
            tl.removeView(row); 
            row.removeView(s[index]);                   
            Log.w("Row Parent " + row.getParent()," tl child " + tl.getChildCount());
            tl.addView(row, index + 4 , tlp);
            row.addView(s[index]);
            Log.w("Row Parent After Add" + row.getParent()," tl child After Add" + tl.getChildCount());
            row.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);                    
            s[index].setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            s[index].setPromptId(R.string.Sub);
            s[index].setAdapter(adapterDataNew);

            Log.w("ID: Landscape mode", "index=" + adapterDataNew.getItemId(pos) + " " + adapterDataNew.getCount());
        }   
        else {
            s[index].setVisibility(view.GONE);
            row.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            row.removeView(s[index]);
            tl.removeView(row);                 
        }

}

}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {        

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
EditText et1 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.entry);
EditText et2 = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.entry2);
String lastName = et1.getText().toString();
String firstName = et2.getText().toString();
if (lastName.length() == 0) {
    lastName = "%";
}
if (firstName.length() == 0) {
    firstName = "%";
}
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("LastName", lastName);
bundle.putString("FirstName", firstName);
switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Search:
        Intent i = new  Intent(this, Search.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
        c2.close();
        c3.close();
        break;
    case R.id.Near_Me:
        Intent j = new  Intent(this, SearchNearMe.class);
        startActivity(j);

}       
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hip Hip Array for your help, I will try your codes and will also mark it as an answer if it works.